# React native webview load big javascript cca 7MB and bigger NOT POSSIBLE?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm developing an app which shows offline webpage. I need to download CSS, HTML and JS. Before 5 days JS had about 3MB and everything work good. But now this JS have around 8MB and it stops working.
I don't use injectedJavaScript, I'm sending content to WebView as:

I'm tried injectedJavaScript too but show a white page.

```
let posionOfHead = this.state.htmlToDisplay.indexOf("<head>");
let doctype = this.state.htmlToDisplay.substring(0, posionOfHead+6);
let toDisplay = doctype  + this.state.cssCode + this.state.jsCode + this.state.htmlToDisplay.slice(posionOfHead+6);

<WebView
 originWhitelist={['*']}
 javaScriptEnabled={true}
 javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
 domStorageEnabled={true}
 source={{ html: toDisplay }}
 onMessage={message => this.onMessage(message)}
          />
```

Is there any limitations of the size of the JS? I load JS from a file and I'm able to see it in the console.